# HTML Video element stopped looping

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a video element on a site I am working on that suddenly stopped looping. The site is https://mystiquepelicanbay.com/. It main background video used to loop indefinitely, but about a week ago, it suddenly stopped. Nothing about the site was changed, so I am baffled by what could be causing it to suddenly stop looping.

It was initially a video element with a loop attribute, which worked up until about a week ago. I have it removed now to try and get it to work with Javascript, but nothing has worked so far.

I have also tried every iteration of event listeners, Jquery binds, and onended functions that I could find online, but none of them worked. I had the loop attribute in the video tag added in and taken out to see if that would affect anything, but no success.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://caniuse.com/#search=video%20loop

Check your browser version, but it looks like your old method should work for most modern browsers.

Comment: My browser is supported, Chrome 77, but it still won't work.